# Why sling:OsgiConfig node not working in /etc/folder in AEM?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, jcr, sling

I have a component with properties as follows.

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true, label = "Conf Details")
@Service(value = { LocationConfigurationUtil.class })
@Properties({
        @Property(label = "location blueprint", name = "locationPath", value = "", description = "..."),
        @Property(label = "location page template", name = "locationTemplate", value = "", description = "..."),
        @Property(label = "basepath live copies", name = "liveCopyRoot", value = "/content/WebRoot", description = "...") })
public class LocationConfigurationUtil {
@Activate
    protected void activate(Map<String, Object> mapCreated) {
          // some code
    }
}
```

To make it editable properties in a jcr node, I used a non-standard method. I created `sling:OsgiConfig` in path `/apps/system/config` having properties declared in java code, which is working fine.

[image: screen shot]

But if I just have the same `sling:OsgiConfig` inside `/etc/myapp/myconfig`, it does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With default settings, JCR Installer Provider does not look for installable bundles and nodes (`sling:OsgiConfig`) in folders other than `/libs` and `/apps`. so any config in `/etc` will not be loaded.

If you want to change this behavior, make a search path entry in "Apache Sling JCR Installer" config in osgi configuration console. But be aware it is not recommended, you should not be putting any `sling:osgiconfig` node in `/etc` in the first place.

Comment: It started working in `/etc/system/config/`, after adding `/etc:300`. But inside folder `/etc/myapp/myconfig` still not working.

Comment: Rename the folder myconfig to config.

Answer (score 5):

Note that placing configuration nodes under `/etc` is a really bad idea.

From a security point of view, `/libs` and `/apps` are locked down, but with `/etc/` you open yourself up to at least two major security holes:

- OSGi configurations can be read by anonymous users
- Code can be deployed by unprivileged users

Please reconsider adding the `/etc` path to the JCR Installers search path entries and instead deploy your configurations to `/apps`.